# How JavaScript compares same DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, dom

Today i'm facing a question, I have three similar texts, they are really identical.

And with a little script, I can actually find the exact text on which I have clicked, even if they are really similar, that's crazy, how JavaScript is doing that ?

```js
const allTxt = document.querySelectorAll('.txt');

allTxt.forEach(item => {
    
    item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        
        const itemClick = e.target;

        for(i = 0; i < allTxt.length; i++) {

            if(itemClick === allTxt[i]){
                console.log(itemClick);
            }

        }

    })

})
```

```html
<p class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla asperiores placeat quidem sint in harum.</p>
<p class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla asperiores placeat quidem sint in harum.</p>
<p class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla asperiores placeat quidem sint in harum.</p>
```

If you hover the result on the console, you can see that the text you clicked on is highlighted.

How does JS compare two DOM elements ? Is there some kind of hidden attribute ? Does it compares the DOM elements as raw text ? If so how he can find which one I cliked on ?

Thank's for your light !

Comment: It's not magic. In your code `allTxt[i]` and `itemClick` are two different references to the same, one DOM element, so they will always be equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not magic. In your code `allTxt[i]` and `itemClick` are two different references to the same, one DOM element, so they will always be equal. It's like when my wife says "Scott" and my kids say "dad", both ways refer to the one me.

JavaScript doesn't compare values of an element when testing to see if two elements are the same, it tests **object references** to see if the two references reference the same object instance in memory. You are just using two different ways to reference the same object in your function.

Some examples:

```js
const par1 = document.querySelector("p");
const par2 = par1.nextElementSibling;
const par3 = par2.nextElementSibling;

console.log(par1 === par2); // false: two different instances of a paragraphElement
console.log(par2 === par3); // false: two different instances of a paragraphElement
console.log(par1 === par3); // false: two different instances of a paragraphElement

// This creats a second reference to the first paragraph
const par1a = document.querySelector(".txt"); 
console.log(par1 === par1a); // true: two different references to same instance of a paragraphElement
```

```html
<p class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit. Nulla asperiores placeat quidem sint in harum.</p>
<p class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit. Nulla asperiores placeat quidem sint in harum.</p>
<p class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit. Nulla asperiores placeat quidem sint in harum.</p>
```

All objects in JavaScript have to be stored in memory and the details of how that is done is really up to each browser implementation, but this generally means that a "memory address" is used to keep track of each unique object. Much like when you drive through a neighborhood where all the houses are the same, you need the street address to keep them straight. It is these memory addresses that are used when objects are compared. If the house at 20 Main Street is the same as the house at 20 Main Street, then there really is only one house, but perhaps more than one "map" with directions on how to get to it.

So, when you ask:

> Is there some kind of hidden attribute?

The answer is yes, the internal memory address is how the system keeps track of unique objects.

And when you ask:

> If so how he can find which one I clicked on?

The answer is to check `event.target` within an event handler (which you are already doing). Here's a better example of that:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  console.log("You clicked on the paragraph that has the text of: " + event.target.textContent);
});
```

```html
<h1>Click on any of the paragraphs below:</h1>
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
<p>Paragraph 3</p>
```

Comment: Wow now this is a great response Scott ! You deserve an upvote + I love the way you teach things, with comparisons and metaphors. Have a nice day/night! :)

Answer (score 0):

What you describe as "your text" are seen as "DOM Elements" by the Javascript.

DOM Elements are nodes that are all distincts one from another, even if their HTML is the same.

When you do your comparaison, JavaScript will compare the nodes references, not the node content as a string.

Answer (score 0):

The console doesn't just contain text. When you log an object, it keeps a reference to the actual object that was logged (this allows the log to update if the object is modified). And if the object is a DOM element, hovering over the log message will highlight the corresponding element in the page.

Answer (score -1):

Because you added click event, every item with forEach.

```
allTxt.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        //
    });
});
```

now every '.txt' class item has a click listener.

Comment: That's not what they asked.